# Override var in Collapse.prototype.show in bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to override the following var in the Collapse prototype bootstrap.js:

```
var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.children('.panel').children('.in, .collapsing')
```

with this

```
var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('.panel').find('.in, .collapsing')
```

The reason for this is to make all accordeons uncollapse when one accordeon is opened.
For this to work they usually have to be directly under the parent div which is their data-parent.
when using .find instead of .children they can be nested inside s (Meaning they don´t need to be directly one level below the data-parent ) which is a formal requirement of the website im trying to build.

I would rather not alter the bootstrap.js (or the minified version) but override it with a custom.js loaded after the bootstrap.js

So far my approach was this:

```
// save original Fuction to tmp
var tmp = $.fn.collapse.Constructor.prototype.show;
//set prototype to new function
$.fn.collapse.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
//set var
var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('.panel').find('.in, .collapsing')
//call saved function
    tmp.call(this);
}
```

But unfortunately this is not working. i made a fiddle under http://www.bootply.com/gSm4qppP3Q#

The behaviour should be: if one accordeon is opened, all others with the same data-parent should close.
I even tried redefining the function as a whole, but this didn´t work out as the console shows an "illegal constructor error"

So as more general approach:
How can I change a var inside of bootstrap.js prototype functions from a different js script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. In particular, we need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than working on the internals, I'd use the external API. Bootstrap Collapse offers events, which bubble, and methods. So I'd just respond to the `show.bs.collapse` event by finding all *other* collapses and calling their `hide` method:

```
$(document).on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
    $(".collapse").not(e.target).collapse("hide");
});
```

Naturally, if you want to target more narrowly, add a class to the ones in question and use that instead of (or in addition to) `.collapse` above.

Example:

```js
$(document).on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
  // Get the data-parent from the link for this collapse.
  // It's a bit awkward, because e.target is the div, not
  // the link.
  var parent = $("[data-toggle=collapse][href='#" + e.target.id + "']").attr("data-parent");
  // Collapse all others with the same data-parent and hide them; again a bit awkward because we have
  // to find the links, then find what they toggle
  var targets = $("[data-toggle=collapse][data-parent='" + parent + "']").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("href");
  }).get().join(",");
  console.log(targets);
  $(targets).not(e.target).collapse("hide");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parentA" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
    <div class="well">
      I'm <code>#collapse1</code>, my data-parent is <code>#parentA</code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parentA" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
    <div class="well">
      I'm <code>#collapse2</code>, my data-parent is <code>#parentA</code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parentB" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse3">
    <div class="well">
      I'm <code>#collapse3</code>, my data-parent is <code>#parentB</code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parentB" href="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse4">
    <div class="well">
      I'm <code>#collapse4</code>, my data-parent is <code>#parentB</code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think i misslead you by saying the accordeons need to be nested.
What I actually meant was: The data-parent should not need to be directly one level above the accordeons.
If you open one accordeon having the same data-parent, all others with the same data-parent should close even if they are sereval levels blow that level.

Comment: @SebAstian: Ah, that would be closer to my original answer which showed collapsing *all* other Collapses. (I thought I'd misunderstood and updated it.) We just need to add a filter to what we collapse, based on `data-parent`.

Comment: @SebAstian: I've updated the answer. It's made complicated by the fact that `data-parent` is on the links rather than the divs. If you can move that, it will simplify things. Note that the code in the answer relies on the links using `href` (rather than `data-target`); adjust as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i edited the question to clearify the wanted behaviour. And i guess it´s time for me to get started with the api @ http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ it seems rather mighty.